# Using an object literal as the default property value for an ActionScript 3 class

Tags: actionscript-3

If I am using an object literal as the default value for a property in ActionScript, will this create a *single* object which is referenced by all instances, or a new object for each instances?

For example, if I created multiple instances of this `AddressBook`...

```
class AddressBook {
    private var numbersByName:Object = {};

    public function addNumber(name:String, number:String):void {
        numbersByName[name] = number;
    }

    public function getNumber(name:String):String {
        return numbersByName[name];
}
```

...would they behave properly, or would they use the same `numbersByName` object, causing all changes in one also apply to the others?

---

Even if each `AddressBook` instance does get its own object, it's conceivable that Flash might only apply this behaviour shallowly. Consider a default of nested object literals:

```
class AddressBook {
    private var indicies:Object = {
        numberToName: {},
        nameToNumber: {}
    };

    public function addNumber(name:String, number:String):void {
        indicies.numberToName[number] = name;
        indicies.nameToNumber[name] = number;
    }

    public function getName(number:String):String {
        return indicies.numberToName[number];
    }

    public function getNumber(number:String):String {
        return indicies.nameToNumber[number];
    }
}
```

Is the entire nested literal created anew for each instance, or do the different `indicies` objects share the same `numberToName` objects?

---

Generally, will there be a between the properties of a class whose property has an object literal default...

```
class MyClass {
    private var myProperty:Object = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: { d: 4, e: 5 } };
}
```

...and one which initializes it in the constructor?

```
class MyClass {
    private var myProperty:Object;
    public function MyClass() {
        myProperty = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: { d: 4, e: 5 } };
    }
}
```

Comment: the var is not set as STATIC so each new implementation will result in the default value set in the class at compile time which in this case is just an object with 2 properties that are empty objects.

Comment: However in this case I would recommend abstracting "indicies" into its own class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely new objects will be created, none will be re-used. You get the same result whether you use the simple `AddressBook` or the one with nested object literals:

```js
trace("None instantiated yet.")

var a:* = new AddressBook;
trace("A instantiated.");

var b:* = new AddressBook; 
trace("B instantiated.");

a.addNumber("John", "555-5555");
trace(a.getNumber("John")); // prints 555-5555
trace(b.getNumber("John")); // prints null
```

Set a breakpoint inside of the object literal. What is the output when it breaks the first time?

```
None instantiated yet.
```

The second time?

```
None instantiated yet.
A instantiated.
```

The object literal is evaluated each time an instance is created, and at no other time.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find a definitive reference for this behaviour. The ActionScript "specification" doesn't contain enough detail. Better references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance of your class, it will have its own unique variables.

So

```
var class_a:AddressBook = new AddressBook();
var class_b:AddressBook = new AddressBook();

class_a.var = 1;
class_b.var = 2;
trace(class_a.var) //traces 1.
```